# What are the regulations on flying UAVs over people on the ground?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

We are considering a project related to drones and in my discussions with people I heard that flying UAVs overhead people (crowds or otherwise) is banned. I also heard this is the case for the USA and EU. I searched and couldn't find the related detailed explanations anywhere.

I would be grateful if somebody could shed some light and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Useful site: http://knowbeforeyoufly.org/for-recreational-users/

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb is "don't do anything hazardous for people or property on the ground".

In the US, [do not intentionally fly over unprotected persons or moving vehicles, and remain at least 25 feet away from individuals and vulnerable property](http://knowbeforeyoufly.org/for-recreational-users/).

Based on whether your project is for recreation or not, how heavy the drone is,... you may not be able to do the same things. The FAA website has a page titled ``[What Can You Do With Your Unmanned Aircraft?](https://www.faa.gov/uas/what_can_you_do_with_your_uas/)'' that gives details on what you can and can't do based on these parameters.

[A document published by EASA](http://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/204696_EASA_concept_drone_brochure_web.pdf#5) states that for low-risk drone operations:

> Flights above crowds are prohibited, but flights above people not related to the operation in cities or populated areas is allowed.

Refer also to local laws. A number of states and municipalities have passed or are considering limitations on unmanned aircraft.